# Call a function with a Function object node.js

Tags: node.js

I have to work with strings to execute functions. So I created a new function where i put the string. It works but not when I want to call a specific function in another module :

```
var mymodule = require('./mymodule');
```

...

```
mymodule.function(a, b); //Works

var functionTest1= new Function('var a = 2; console.log(a*a);');  
functionTest1(); //Works

var functionTest2= new Function('mymodule.function(a, b)');
functionTest2(); //Doesn't work (error console : mymodule is not defined)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an other way to do it ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? *I have to work with strings to execute functions.* Why?

Comment: Because the string come from a module which is an observer. So if I want in the futur another behavior i just have to add another module observer and write a new function with a string. (I don't know if it's the best idea but i found this flexible)

Comment: Your example works completely fine for me in the node REPL. I accidentally reproduced your error by mis-typing mymodule as myModule. Perhaps it was just a typo?

Comment: no @chriskelly, lurii is right, i forgot to add mymodule in parameter ^^

Comment: strange. I didn't need to pass mymodule. it was already in scope.

Comment: Personnaly, I have to pass all the variables i use (including socket and io for socket.io)

Comment: @chriskelly: it probably worked in the repl because everything in the repl is in global scope. But if you are inside a module, Imports are module scoped, whereas functions created with the Function constructor are declared in global scope.

Comment: Using the function constructor is likely the wrong approach. If you’d provide a more complete example we could probably suggest a better solution.

Comment: @FelixKling: Seems you are right! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @FelixKling   I have a main.js which discuss with the client with websockets (socket.io). I have also many modules linked with main.js which are my plugins.js. The plugins have the same nature: for example "character" will be the abstract class of the plugins, and one of the plugins could be "warrior". My plugins can't discuss with the client directly and I must pass again by the main.js (maybe that point of view is wrong). I want each module that I add on the project have no influence on the code of main.js.

Comment: So I thought I could send a string from the plugin to my main.js, because I can access to all my modules and variables in the scope of main.js. (for example: `var codeForWeapon= “mymodule.equipWeapon(socket.myCharacter, typeOfWeapon); socket.emit('armed');”; ) ` That's why I try to use the function constructor. If you have any suggestion or want more information it would be very helpful.

Comment: Note quite sure I understand but it seems like you just need a generic way to generate and react to events (for communication)? Have a look at pub sub: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you it was very helpful, I don't use the function constructor anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var functionTest3 = new Function('mymodule','a','b', 'mymodule.function(a, b)');
functionTest3(mymodule, a, b);
```

> Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures
>   to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global
>   scope. When running them, they will only be able to access their own
>   local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which
>   the Function constructor was called.

More to read here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: You might want to explain why this works and/or what the problem with the OPs code is.

Comment: @Felix Kling  yeah, sure